There are two solutions for one board, using different chips. But one of their i2c address is the same. How to resolve conflict in one dts?
Two chips A and B conflict with 0x62 on i2c bus 10. If A@62 and B@62 are configured on dts, Linux loads the driver of A. If B@62 is in front, it will load the driver of B. Whoever is in front will Which driver will be loaded, and is there any way to make the two chips compatible in one DTS.
i2cdetect -r -y 10
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- UU -- UU -- UU --
60: UU -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
i2cdetect -r -y 10
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:                         -- -- -- -- 0c -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 28 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 37 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- UU 62 UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- UU -- UU UU -- --
Hardware can't modify the address. If two dts are used, there will be two firmwares, which is inconvenient.

My experience in the past leads me to say something you might not be hoping to hear.   When there are multiple i2c devices with the same slave address on the same i2c bus there are no winners.  As soon as the master attempts to communicate with any device at that address on that bus, all the devices will react, and reliable communication with any of them is not possible.  This is an electrical problem that a DT can't fix.
